# Xpath for getting all element after this element before any other element or end of elements?

Tags: xpath

I get category like this

```
a[contains(@class,'category')])[*]
```

I try this for getting sub category, but I can't get second part.

```
((a[@class='category'])[2]//following-sibling::a[@class='sub_category'][following-sibling::a[@class='category')]])[*]
```

How i can get second part?

```html
<div class="categories">                             
<a class="category" href="#">A</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">B</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">BB</a> 
<a class="sub_category" href="#">BBB</a> 
<a class="category" href="#">AA</a>   
<a class="sub_category" href="#">B</a> 
<a class="sub_category" href="#">BB</a> 
<a class="sub_category" href="#">BBB</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">BBBB</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">ВBBBB</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">ВBBBBB</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">ВBBBBBB</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">ВBBBBBBB</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please try xpath `//a[@class='category' and text()='AA']/following-sibling::a[@class='sub_category']`

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all the a's where class is equal to 'sub_category' after second category

```
//a[@class='category'][2]/following-sibling::a[@class='sub_category']
```

also bear in mind that it will include all "sub_category" a's 
e.g

```
<div class="categories">
<a class="category" href="#">A</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">B</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">BB</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">BBB</a>
<a class="category" href="#">AA</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">B</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">BB</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">BBB</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">BBBB</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">ВBBBB</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">ВBBBBB</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">ВBBBBBB</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">ВBBBBBBB</a>
<a class="category" href="#">AAA</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">B</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">BB</a>
<a class="sub_category" href="#">BBB</a>
</div>
```

The above xpath will also include a's under AAA category

If you need to extract only selected a's, you can do something like below:

```
//a[@class='category' and text()='AA']/following-sibling::a[@class='sub_category'][position()<8]
```